# How can I enter a variable into a string? Between some text?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I only can do something like this: 
`member.guild.channels.get('######').send('dsadsadas - '+var);`
and it sends: "dsadsadas and value of variable"
but I want to make something like this: "Text variable text". Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you're using the [concatenation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators) (`+`) to join a string with the value of a variable, you can use the same exact concept to join another string with the previous union.

```js
'string 1 ' + variable + ' string 2'
```

As of EMCAScript 6 (referred to as ES6), you can now make use of [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). The string *must* be enclosed in back-ticks/graves (`` ` ``). To embed an expression or variable, use the `${}` template.

```js
`string 1 ${variable} string 2`
```

Both of these structures produce the same result.

```js
let name = 'ohdudeeee';

console.log('Hey, ' + name + '. How are you?');
console.log(`Hey, ${name}. How are you?`);
```